# unable to click and enter text for Dynamic Form using seleninum java

Tags: java, selenium, dynamicform

i was unable click and enter text using selenium java here is sample text path

scLocator=//DynamicForm[ID="CollapseView_RuleGrid_activeView_RuleForm"]/item[name=name1||title=title1||index=26||Class=CanvasItem]/canvas/member[Class=Canvas||index=1||length=2||classIndex=0||classLength=1]/

scLocator=//DynamicForm[ID="CollapseView__RuleGrid_activeView_RuleForm"]/item[name=name2||title=title1||index=26||Class=CanvasItem]/canvas/member[Class=Canvas||index=1||length=2||classIndex=0||classLength=1]/

how click and enter text

everything is  same except title and name
i want click first name and enter text
then click second one name and enter text

### screen

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: #1.capture the element using xpath
WebElement webElement = SmartGwtUtil.getWebElement(String.format("//DynamicForm[ID=\"%s\"]/item[name=%s]/canvas/member[Class=Canvas||index=1||classIndex=0]/", getId(), editorName), 1);

#2.then look canvas items 
List<WebElement> aceCanvasses = webElement.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='AceCanvas']")).stream().filter(WebElement::isDisplayed).
    collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: #3.then look for size
int index = aceCanvasses.size();

Comment: 4# find list of editors
List<WebElement> aceEditors = aceCanvasses.get(index-1).findElements(By.id("AceEditor_" + editorName));

Comment: #4.then click and enter text
if (aceEditors.size() == 1) {
   WebDriver webDriver = Setup.getDriver();
   final ExpectedCondition<WebElement> successCondition = ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(aceCanvasses.get(index-1));
   new Actions(webDriver).moveToElement(aceCanvasses.get(index-1)).click().perform();
   new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 3).until(successCondition);
   Retry.retry(() -> ((RemoteWebElement)aceEditors.get(0)).findElementByClassName("ace_text-input").sendKeys(value));
  }
 }

Comment: i followed the above mentioned steps  . it was click and entering first editor then next editor just clicking not typing it